# How to center a block on a page?

Tags: blocks, css, magento2.3, page-layouts

I have a block with a visual menu in it and I want to show up centered on the page. This is my css within the block:

```
.container{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

I've also tried to put the widget when inserted into the page inside a centered div:

```
<div style="text-align: center;" >
{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" template="widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="38" type_name="CMS Static Block"}}
</div>
```

What else can I do to center it?

Answer (score 0):

What about if you create a new template file

template="widget/static_block/whatever.phtml

And put markup to center content within this. Obviously depends on the content of template file as to whether this works

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, could you put a link to instructions for this? Thanks